# Why are high-voltage circuit breakers not automated?

Tags: high-voltage, safety, power-engineering

I came across a [video from Ontario Power Generation](https://www.therobotreport.com/ontario-power-generation-tests-boston-dynamics-spot-to-save-lives/) about them using a fancy Boston Dynamics robot to trip a high-voltage circuit breaker because it’s too dangerous to do it manually.

I was interested what the deal with these devices routinelly killing workers was so did some youtube “research”. It seems that these breakers have a tendency to create electrical arcs that may kill the worker handling them.

Why isn't opening / closing or even  disconnection and removal performed by some actuator or a motorised mechanism? What the operators or the robots do doesn’t look like a complicated procedure requiring a human element. Why are these devices not motorized and therefore much less likely to kill the operators?

Comment: What causes arcs?

Comment: This may have more to do with minimizing exposure to nuclear radiation than auto tripping breakers.

Comment: @StainlessSteelRat it’s got nothing to do with radiation. The HV breakers tend to arc / flesh / explode when opening or closing. That should be easy to automate and not require people to do it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The video wasn't about merely activating or deactivating a breaker.  The video is about replacing a defective breaker without shutting off associated systems.

A human could safely activate or deactivate the breaker if it weren't broken.

For a human to safely replace the broken breaker, they would have had to shut down the power at the next higher point in the system.  Doing that would have shut down power to other large power consumers.  That shutdown would have had to be coordinated with all the other consumers.  That would be acceptable dates and times for disruptions, and probably also alternative, temporary power sources.  The video said just getting that coordinated could take from months to as much as a year.

In this case, the power company decided to use a robot to shut off the breaker and replace it with the system still powered.  Any error or unexpected event could kill a human.  The robot is replaceable.

1. They didn't need to use the robot just to turn a breaker on or off.  They used the robot to turn off and replace a defective breaker.
2. Such equipment is made to last.  It is unusual to replace it outside of scheduled maintenance or replacement plans.  Installing equipment to do something that shouldn't happen would be a waste.  Not just the installation, but also the maintenance. You would have to maintain the breakers as well as the permanently installed "remote breaker replacement" equipment.

---

As TooTea mentioned in a comment, there are [automated high voltage circuit breakers called "reclosers."](https://www.eaton.com/us/en-us/products/medium-voltage-power-distribution-control-systems/reclosers/reclosers--fundamentals-of-reclosers.html)

When tripped by a short circuit, they make several attempts to reset.  Before each reset, they perform measurements of the affected line to see if the fault has cleared.

The control unit for the recloser is separate from the recloser itself.  This allows the control unit to be placed somewhere safe for a human to operate it.  Not "miles away," but far enough that an arc flash or explosion of the recloser merely causes an unscheduled change of underwear instead of a trip to the morgue.

Comment: You could also mention that something like OP's automated HV breaker actually exists, it's called a recloser,and it can easily turn itself on as well as off in response to a fault.